# Java time: preserve date and time to other timezone

Tags: java, java-time

Is it able to get same date&time in other time zone?

I mean, currently, I'm getting a zulu datetime from database. This is:

> 2019-04-02T00:00:00Z

I'd need to keep date&time part in other timezone (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`). I'd like to get:

> 2019-04-02T00:00:00+02:00[Europe/Madrid]

Is it able to get it?

Comment: If you’re only after the date and the time will never be anything other than 00:00, consider a `LocalDate`. It’s a date without time of day.

Comment: @OleV.V. With LocalDate you cannot have a Zone however. I think that's important for OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this is possible, and pretty easy to do.

```
final String dateStr = "2019-04-02T00:00:00Z";
final ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr);
final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Output:

```
date:          2019-04-02T00:00Z
zonedDateTime: 2019-04-02T00:00+02:00[Europe/Rome]
```

---

`withZoneSameLocal` is doing the magic

> Returns a copy of this date-time with a different time-zone, retaining
>   the local date-time if possible.